# Sqlite Join to a Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sqlite

I'm accustomed to doing this in Oracle (and I think even SqlServer a while back), but I haven't figured out how to do it in sqlite.

A standard "simple" join in sqlite can be done like so:

```
select *
from kennel k
    join kennelbreeder kb
    on kb.kennelid = k.rowid;
```

But if I want to also get some information from the breeder, based on my experience elsewhere, I would expect the following to work, but it doesn't:

```
select *
from kennel k
    join kennelbreeder kb
        join breeder b
        on kb.breederid = b.rowid
    on kb.kennelid = k.rowid;
```

The error I get is `'Error: near "on": syntax error'`. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why the downvotes? It seems like a clear, answerable question, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sqlite, joins may not be nested:

```
select *
from kennel k
    join kennelbreeder kb ON kb.kennelid = k.rowid;
    join breeder b on kb.breederid = b.rowid
```

Comment: "invalid in every DBMS including Oracle..." is simply incorrect. Concerning sqlite, putting the joins next to each other rather than inside does seem to have the desired effect. The thought is: I don't want to join the breeder table to the kennel table, I want to join breeder to kennelbreeder (which is joined to kennel). In Oracle, I always write these nested.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement: you are right. I misread your syntax. But there is actually no difference between nesting the joins and writing them "serially"  (at least not for an inner join)

Comment: That makes sense that they're semantically the same, but I think the nested syntax is easier to read. When listing them serially without visual and positional context, one winds up asking, "Now to what am I joining?" especially when you're joining the same table multiple times. For instance, 'person', 'class', and 'studentclass' table: a class has a teacher (from person) and a class has multiple students (again from person). To create a "full" query will require joining the person into the query twice.

Answer (score 2):

The `on` must follow the `join`. It's just a question about the correct order.

```
select *
from kennel k
    join kennelbreeder kb
        on kb.kennelid = k.rowid
    join breeder b
        on kb.breederid = b.rowid;
```

Your second example seems to be based on the syntax with nested joins which I've only seen used in MS Access, but it's always with parentheses, which are missing in your example. It would seem that this query works with both MS SQL and SQLite3, and possibly other databases too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM kennel k
    JOIN ( kennelbreeder kb 
        JOIN breeder b
        ON kb.breederid = b.rowid )
    ON kb.kennelid = k.rowid;
```

I wouldn't recommend using the latter syntax though as it's unclear and not the standard way of writing joins.

Comment: Looks like you're quite an editor! I edited your second SQL to make it look similar to my second SQL. It looks like I was missing `(` after the frist `JOIN`, and `)` before the last `ON`. I have never written it this way, so I guess the sum of it is that oracle figured out how to infer these parentheses, and I had relied on that feature when I learned multiple joins.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement So it would seem; although I would strongly recommend the standard way of writing the joins, without nesting. I've been doing database stuff since the early 90s and the only times I've seen the nested syntax is in code generated by Access - I've never seen it written by a person :)